# CKEditorError: ckeditor-duplicated-modules

Tags: javascript, ckeditor5

I'm customizing ckeditor5, It can build successfully but when implemented it has an error saying "CKEditorError: ckeditor-duplicated-modules". I'm not sure what module duplicated.

**In my code imported**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try to install the plugins of the same version (it works for me) like:

check ckeditor5-core version first

`@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core": "^33.0.0"`

If you want to add "table" tool, use

`npm i @ckeditor/ckeditor5-table@33.0.0"`

to get specified version, instead of

`npm i @ckeditor/ckeditor5-table`

you may get a newer version, which needs the second ckeditor5-core package lead to duplicated-modules (now you know which module is duplicated)

Comment: This solved my own issue. I was following the directions to add the [`FindAndReplace` plugin](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/find-and-replace.html) to my existing project, but `npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-find-and-replace` installed the latest version, which was different than my existing project. I ran into the "ckeditor-duplicated-modules" issue, and this was the correct solution for me. Thank you!