# ckeditor mention not installing properly and not working

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor, ckeditor5, mention

I am working with CKeditor5 and ckeditor mention in react https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/mentions.html#demo

but this package doesnt seem to install properly and gives error like this

"Uncaught CKEditorError: ckeditor-duplicated-modules"

when I try install separately like this
npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-react @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic
and then npm i @ckeditor/ckeditor5-mention
and if I install like this
npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-react @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic @ckeditor/ckeditor5-mention
it gives me [ckeditor error when installing packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/malzH.png)

my code
`

```
 import { CKEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react'
 import { Mention } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-mention'
 import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic'

 const CreatePage = () => {
 return (
 <div>
   <h2>CKEditor with Mentions</h2>
   <CKEditor
     editor={ClassicEditor}
      config={{
       plugins: [Mention],
      toolbar: ['mention', 'bold', 'italic', 'link'],
      mention: {
        feeds: [
          {
            marker: '@',
            feed: ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie'], // Replace with your mentionable data
          },
        ],
      },
    }}
  />
 </div>
 )
}

export default CreatePage`
```

I have tried installing all modules separately and all modules together but ckeditor doesn't render and work properly with  @ckeditor/ckeditor5-mention

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CKEditorError: ckeditor-duplicated-modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71656912/ckeditorerror-ckeditor-duplicated-modules)

Comment: No tried this right now but still gives same error.
Thank you for the reply

Comment: I've no experience with CKEditor in React. Are you sure that you need both packages 'CKEditor' and 'ClassicEditor'? I can imagine that you need only this line `import { CKEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react'` and the next one for { Mention }, but not the 3rd one. The line more below would be then `editor={ CKEditor }`

Comment: @David no that line is necessary without that the editor doesnt load and editor={ CKEditor } is just wrong wrong